# How can we install Java in a Linux server if we don't have sudo rights?

Tags: java, linux, unix, server, elf

I searched a lot about installing Java without sudo rights oneline and at lastly found [this solution](https://java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml).

After following the above solution, I ran the following command:

```
java -version
```

But got the following response:

> -bash: /home/{user Dirctoory}/java/jre1.8.0_131/bin/java: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

When I searched online, I found that this error comes when some files are missing and found following the commands to run:

1. `yum install gtk2.i686`

   But got the following response:

   > -bash: yum: command not found
2. `pkcon install glibc.i686`

   > -bash: pkcon: command not found**

How can I fix these?

Comment: You don't have to "install" Java. It's only important that applications using the JVM find the path to the Java directory later on.

Comment: The `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` sounds like you're trying to run a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit system.  It's possible to make that work by installing 32-bit libraries (as it looks like you're trying to do), but it'd be simpler to just install a 64-bit JVM.

Answer (score 0):

You can get zip file from respective JDK providers (example Eclipse Temurin https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?os=linux) and unzip in your local home directory.  Once you set PATH environment variable, it should work.

In IntelliJ you can install multiple JDK's these get copied to /.jdks.  Very similar to that you can simply unpack JDK's into your home directory to use it.  You would not need Linux sudo to do this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).